# Set test parameter in test instance using HP QC REST API

Tags: rest, hp-quality-center

Is there any way to create test instance with parameter using the REST API on QC 11 ?

I have a test in my test plan with some parameters, or just one for the exercise :
[image: qc parameters]

I want to create using the rest API :

- A test set in my test lab
- A test instance in this test set
- A test run of my test (the one in the plan) in this test instance
- **And be able to set the value of my parameters**

I have manage to do the first 3 points. But I can not find how to set the parameter value for my instance. If I create the tests manually it is asked during the add of the test in the instance. And I can find the parameters in the Execution Settings in the Test Instance detail :

[image: test instance details]

I have search in the documentation, but didn't find anything about how to set/use theses parameters. I have made GET on every objects, but didn't find them. I also try some urls like :

```
/test-instances/25378/test-parameters
/test-instances/25378/execution-settings
/test-instances/25378/exec-settings
```

But they always return 404.

Is there any way to set these parameters values ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same troubles and here is my solution.

You can query your test parameters as:

```
/tests/{id}/test-parameters
```

And your test instance parameters, which are effectively actual values for those in your test instance, with:

```
/test-instances/{id}/step-parameters
```

For parameter values created via UI it returns like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Entities TotalResults="1">
    <Entity Type="step-parameter">
        <ChildrenCount>
            <Value>0</Value>
        </ChildrenCount>
        <Fields>
            <Field Name="origin-test">
                <Value>-1</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field Name="vc-user-name">
                <Value></Value>
            </Field>
            <Field Name="id">
                <Value>21</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field Name="parent-id">
                <Value>46</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field Name="used-by-owner-type">
                <Value>test-instance</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field Name="actual-value">
                <Value>&lt;html&gt;&lt;body&gt;
                    &lt;div align=&quot;left&quot;&gt;
                    &lt;font face=&quot;Arial&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-size:8pt&quot;&gt;AAA&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/font&gt;
                    &lt;/div&gt;
                    &lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field Name="key">
                <Value></Value>
            </Field>
            <Field Name="used-by-owner-id">
                <Value>34</Value>
            </Field>
        </Fields>
        <RelatedEntities/>
    </Entity>
</Entities>
```

Where `used-by-owner-id` is id of the test-instance and `parent-id` is id of test parameter of the test.
Actual value for this case is `AAA` wrapped up with html tags.

You can create step parameters like this using normal POST to url:

```
/step-parameters
```

**Note:** Don't use same nested url for creation as you use for retrieval. You'll not be able to create parameters with such a combination of parameters you need.

API documentation really sucks, but you can get ideas how to retrieve or create things you need by requesting entity schema with

```
/customization/entities
```